# android WebView stop Flash plugin onPause

Tags: android, flash, onpause

I have a WebView that contains a html file that contains a Flash plugin (a video).

When the user presses play on the Flash plugin, the video plays fine.

However when the user closes the app or moves to a new Activity, the Flash is still playing in the background. Going back to the view appears to create a new thread with the Flash plugin running on it.

How can we stop the Flash plugin running onPause?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same issue. The following worked for me:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    final WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webPlayer);
    // Calling .clearView does not stop the flash player must load new data
    webview.loadData("", "text/html", "utf-8");
}
```

Comment: You should call `super.onDestroy()` as last method in your `onDestroy()` (it's opposite in "building" calls like `onCreate()` etc where you have to call super class as soon as possible. Not to mention I would rather call that earlier, in `onPause()` or `onStop()`

Answer (score -1):

try this.

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && webview.canGoBack()) {
        webview.goBack();
       return true;
    }
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //webview=null;
        webview.reload();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
```

Pavan